# Excel formula to lookup the last value in a column and return the value of the adjacent cell

Tags: excel-formula

I have the following formula to return the value of the last value in a column:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(D:D<>""),D:D)
```

What I need now is to return the value of the cell adjacent to it as well. (It will not necessarily be the last value in that column and the info in Column D could have duplicates.

Comment: You can use `index` & `match` instead of `lookup`s. [Search and search](https://www.google.com/search?q=index+match)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So I have found an answer by playing around with array formulas.

The problem was that this is a stock control sheet where there are changes made at multiple times, each recorded in the next available row. There is always a date (Column E) but not necessarily a Supplier, as it might be stock moving out. When a Supplier delivers, the Supplier name is recorded in Column D. In D1 the last supplier is then shown with the following formula.

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(D:D<>""),D:D)
```

I want to then see what date it was last received. The formula I found that works is as follows (Array Formula):

```
=INDEX(E:E,MAX(IF(D:D=D1,ROW(D:D)-ROW(INDEX(D:D,1,1))+1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data looks like this:

```
A   1
A   2
A   3
B   4
B   5
B   6
C   7
```

To get last value this will do the trick:

```
=INDIRECT("B"&COUNTA(A:A))
```

And to get last where value is `A`:

```
=INDIRECT("B"&MATCH("A",A1:A7,0)+COUNTIF(A1:A7,"A")-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use next column:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(D:D<>""),E:E)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is generally how I do it:

```
=XMATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(A:A),0,-1)
```

This is what each part does:

| Parameter | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `FALSE` | Instructs Excel to find the first instance of `FALSE` that it finds |
| `ISBLANK(A:A)` | Takes in the column `A:A` and notionally assigns a value to every item in the column |
| `0` | Means we want an exact match. Probably not necessary to put in, but I think it's good practice anyway |
| `-1` | Instructs Excel to start the search at the bottom/right of the range and work up/left. If you change this to 1 (the default), Excel will begin the search at the top/left and work down/right |

So, taken together, this will search from the bottom of the column `A:A`, until Excel finds the first cell that is not blank, and return that cell.

Also, yes, this equation can be changed to a row format (e.g. `1:1`), and can take a smaller range (e.g. `A1:A20`), but it cannot take a 2-dimensional range (e.g. `A1:B20`).

As a practical matter, this approach is much faster than other approaches (and much faster than you'd think, given it's evaluating against every row/column in the range), and won't get fooled by columns that have empty spaces in them (like with a `COUNTA` style approach).